# PHP website logs me out, what could it be?

Tags: php, logout

I have a PHP application. It is load balanced across 2 servers. The problem is I keep getting logged out of the session I am in (after a long period of time) and I am not sure why. I have not been with this code for very long and am not sure where to start.

It's a Zend Framework application.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sessions are only stored in the server temporarily while cookies can be saved for a long period of time. Using sessions will cause you to log out. You should try using cookies instead.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: I was going to say gremlins, but I like the aftershave reason better.

Comment: I do use cookies but the user has a session once the cookie is authenticated, it doesn't check the cookie every time. I use zend auth stuff.

Comment: I would use CKone - Get the chicks hot. Cookies behind the ear does not hit the note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be how your sessions are managed.

Check the session manager:

```
var_dump(Zend_Session::getOptions());
```

If you get the below:

```
 ["save_handler"]=> string(5) "files" ["save_path"]=> string(13) "/var/lib/php5"
```

Try a session and check that the file is created on one of the web servers but not the other. The options say that it is stored in a file.

If it is then the problem is the session manager. Change the session manager to use the db or memcached (if possible). It needs to be something which could manage users on both server.

Comment: Hi yes I get files. So the session manager is using files. Ok will look into using mencache or something else as the manager. Thanks